# Memgraph: "Not yet implemented: atom expression"

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, memgraphdb

I just started using Memgraph and I sometimes encounter the error message: "Not yet implemented: atom expression" .
First I observed it when trying to use the neo4j-OGM and now I encounter it when checking for relations in a query.

My query looks like this:

```
memgraph> match(n {nameAST: "CallExpression"}) 
match(m) where not (n)-[:CG]->(m) and m.nameParseTree =~ n.nameParseTree 
return n;
Client received exception: Not yet implemented: atom expression '(n)-[:CG]->(m)'
```

Any help here? How can I circumvent this error?

Answer (score 0):

Patterns in expressions are supported in Memgraph in particular functions, like `exists(pattern)`. In other cases, Memgraph does not yet support patterns in functions and that's why you get this error.

But there is a quick fix to avoid this error - use `OPTIONAL MATCH` instead. Check out [patters in expressions](https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/differences/patterns-in-expressions) in Memgraph's docs and let me know if you managed to fix it